# execute bash in cygwin using vba

Tags: bash, vba

I normally run a bash script in cygwin terminal using bash ~/annovar.sh.  I am trying to avoid scripting and am using the VB below to call and execute a bash script.  This is on a windows machine in excel 2010.

VB

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cmd As String
Dim ret As Double
Dim WshShell As Object
Dim plink_object As Object

' Run Linux Commands
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
Set plink_object = WshShell.Run("C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe annovar.sh 66 ""50602_15:56:31_15:56:11_15:56:21;50602_15:57:07_15:56:47_15:56:57""", 1)
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub

the cygwin terminal starts but says:
annovar.sh: No such file or directory

annovar.sh is in C:\cygwin\bin\

should it be somewhere else?  and what does 66 ""50602_15:56:31_15:56:11_15:56:21;50602_15:57:07_15:56:47_15:56:57""", 1) refer to?  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the full file path of "annovar.sh" as the cmd window will normally be created in the standard system32 directory. In regards to the rest of your question, you will need to look up what the other string is being passed for in the documentation for mintty.exe command line (I'm not familiar with this program.) The final argument of "1" is the window style, this can also be passed as any of the vbWindowStyle enumeration. You can also add a further boolean argument on the end of that `.Run` command to wait for a return.

Looking at what you are trying to do, it would probably make more sense to just make a batch file and call that using the Shell() method.

Final pointer, you're trying to set the run command as an object, which isn't right - if you need to read output from the command line then use the `.Exec().StdOut.ReadAll` method instead.